Plotly bar plot y_axis value
I am not understanding the reason why range on y_axis goes more than around 500k whereas the max value for the column Total_Expenditure 2486. What is the reason of being the value at y axis goes over 500k?
What is the underlying thing going on here or explanation behind it?
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

barchart = px.bar(
data_frame = data,
x = 'Education',
y = 'Total_Expenditure',
color = 'labels3',
barmode ='group',
title='Relationship of Transaction and Education',
width= 900, height= 500,
template= 'plotly_dark'),

barchart.update_traces(marker_line_width = 0,selector=dict(type="bar"))

pio.show(barchart)

I tried to find the reason in different platform. I think the reason is so simple and too basic but i could not figure it out it.
Link of figure:(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SmZEnrLRofwhvOBO60FdJPdqNeYPTlwh/view?usp=sharing)

can you include data in your question so we can reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

@DerekO here is the link of data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HtUZvPI8mHvP47-IqueD3iEM13OxYF1N/view?usp=sharing

are you transforming your data before you pass it to px.bar? I don't see a column called Total_Expenditure

Yes! transformed column. I got the things behind. The values of y_axis has been made in this way: df.groupby('Education')['Total_Expenditure'].sum()

but I don't see any column called Total_Expenditure in the marketing_campaign.csv file that you linked. can you post your full code showing how you go from importing the csv to obtaining data ?

@RotnodipSarkar You should provide your full code. Summing which column based on Education? This certainly is not a plotly issue, but either a data type conversion issue, or the code not doing what you think is supposed to do.
